# Does SmartGit support working with Mercurial repositories?

Tags: mercurial, smartgit

The question is pretty much in the title. Does [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) supports working with Mercurial repos?

I've downloaded the evaluation version, but from what I can see it only supports opening git repos, which is contrary to one of the main statements they make on their frontpage:

*SmartGit is an easy-to-use graphical user interface for **Git, Mercurial and Subversion** with optimized work-flows. SmartGit supports all Git and Mercurial features needed for every-day work in software development projects ...*

Can anyone using SmartGit or familiar with it clarify on this? I really like the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, SmartGit supports Mercurial repositories: just use **Repository|Add or Create** and enter the path of your local Mercurial repository there. In the same way you can clone a remote Mercurial repository, using **Repository|Clone**.

Comment: I don't have Project/Open Repository option. Have Project/Clone ... which offers me to specify a git or svn repository. Have Project/Open working tree and Project/Open which gives a "No project configuration yet" message and does little else.

Comment: I do not wish to modify my local mercurial repo, just open it. Not convert it to git or anything alike.

Comment: "Open Working Tree" sounds like an older version, maybe 2.1? With SmartGit 3 you will have "Open Repository" and you can open your Mercurial repository there without the need to modify/convert it.

Comment: Ah yes, it seems I mislooked that I was using the older version (v2). Sorry about that.

Answer (score 13):

Also note that in SmartGitHg 4, the Mercurial option will *not* appear (e.g. during cloning) if you haven't entered the path to your Mercurial executable in the Preferences: `Edit -> Preferences -> Commands -> Executables -> Hg Executable`

Rough version list (what I could find on random notes around the 'net):
SmartGit 7.1 *should* support Hg 3.6.x.
SmartGit 7.2 *should* support Hg 3.7.x and 3.8.x. ([official changelog](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog.txt))
SmartGit 8.1 *should* support Hg 3.9.x. ([EAP release notes as in Nov 2016](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog-eap.txt), URL will probably soon change)

Comment: What do you mean by `path to your Mercurial executable in the Preferences`?  I don't see this preference path...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky I added the location of the specific setting I was referring to to my answer. Does that help?

Comment: Actually it is quite tricky to locate a binary executable of the old Hg version. I found it here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/files/downloads

Comment: @AlexanderPacha I haven't used Mercurial in a long time, but I would expect that the latest versions of SmartGit (at the time of this writing, I'm using the 8.1 preview) also support the latest Mercurial binaries, no?

Comment: Nope, they still expect 3.7.x. I only cloned a legacy repo. I'm not actually using Hg. Just converting to git and be done with it.

Comment: @AlexanderPacha I just checked, the [release notes for 8.1 preview](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog-eap.txt) explicitly list support for Mercurial 3.9.x!

Comment: OK, but not stable 8.0.3

Comment: @AlexanderPacha [Correct](https://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/changelog.txt). Although I have to note that I'm using preview releases from syntevo most of the time and their preview versions are actually super "stable". So if you need Hg 3.9.x support right now, I would just give it a try, it probably easier than getting an old version of Hg to work.

Answer (score 2):

I am an active user of SmartGit.

It appears it no longer support Mercurial.